# SmartGWT RestDataSource

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT/SmartClient LGPL, I can't use the Pro, due to project ties.

I would like to create a RestDataSource from a jdbc connection, to be exposed from the server to the SmartGWT client.

How could it be done?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the source code for the [RestDataSource Edit & Save](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#restfulds_xml_integration_category) example from the [Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase)?  It's a good starting point.

If you want REST on the server I'd recommend [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) talking to a JDBC backend.  You could take the example above and wire it up to your Restlets instead of the XML.

Comment: hi there,

  do you have any sample code for doing the same ?

thank you,

BR,
~A

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general outline of what you could do if not using GWT and using PHP.  Would be similar idea with java.

Define your DataSource in your file

```
    isc.RestDataSource.create({
     ID: "yourDS"
    ,fields: [
         {name: "id", hidden: true, primaryKey: true}
        ,{name: "name", title: "field1"}
     ]
    ,dataFormat: "json"
    ,dataURL: "dmi/yourDMI.php"
})
```

Then define yourDMI.php controller file.  It should have checks for all the operation types, fetch, add, delete, update

```
    if (isset($_GET['_operationType']) && strcmp($_GET['_operationType'], "fetch") == 0) {
         // do something..  return JSON response
    }

    if (isset($_GET['_operationType']) && strcmp($_GET['_operationType'], "add") == 0) {
         // do something..  return JSON response
    }

    if (isset($_GET['_operationType']) && strcmp($_GET['_operationType'], "delete") == 0) {
         // do something..  return JSON response
    }

    if (isset($_GET['_operationType']) && strcmp($_GET['_operationType'], "update") == 0) {
         // do something..  return JSON response
    }
```

Comment: This user mentioned JDBC which implies a Java backend.  However, for anyone connecting to PHP, on the SmartClient public wiki there is now a series of articles showing how to build PHP server code for RestDataSource that supports full CRUD, including AdvancedCriteria and transactional commits to a database (using the RedBean PHP library): http://wiki.smartclient.com/display/Main/Integrating+with+PHP